# LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection<Results<datatype>>' to expected argument type '[datatype]'

Tags: iphone, swift3, realm, swift2

After I convert my project from swift 2.3 to swift 3 , I got this error in Realm Filter I can't get filter result in array :

```
func filterUsers(_ searchText: String, completion: (([Lawyer]) -> Void)) {

        let bgRealm = try! Realm()            // Filter the whole list of users



let results = bgRealm.objects(Lawyer.self).filter { (cc) -> Bool in
    cc.name.contains2(searchText) ||
        cc.name.contains2(searchText) ||
        cc.phoneNumber2.contains2(searchText)

}
    print(results)


    completion(results)

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Just specify `results` type during declaration, like `let results: [Lawyer]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter`, `map`, etc. are lazy operations on the `Results` returned by `objects`. This is implemented in types such as `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection<T>`. To actually perform the filtering and get an array of results, you need to promote this collection to an array by wrapping in an Array initializer (e.g. `Array(bgRealm.objects...))`

[From the docs:](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries)

> Queries return a Results instance, which contains a collection of
>   Objects. Results have an interface very similar to Array and objects
>   contained in a Results can be accessed using indexed subscripting.
>   Unlike Arrays, Results only hold Objects of a single subclass type.
>   All queries (including queries and property access) are lazy in Realm.
>   Data is only read when the properties are accessed.