# SearchBar Filter base on Object name - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, realm, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a search bar with these data format as a Realm object.

```
Optional(Results<Place> <0x7fb0d9e0bb10> (
[0] Place {
    name = Federal Street;
    country = United States;
    lat = 42.5447229;
    lon = -71.2809886;
},
...
```

I'm trying to make the filter working

[image]

```
//MARK: - Search bar methods
extension PlacesVC : UISearchBarDelegate {



    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        print("searchText \(searchText)")

        places = places.filter { ($0["name"] ?? "").range(of: searchBar.text ?? "", options: [ .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil }

        if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {

            load()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }

        }

        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I kept getting

> Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

**Any hints on what I did wrong ?**

Comment: In `$0["name"]`, `$0` is a `Place` object, no? So I guess it should be `$0.name` depending on how is defined `Place` Also, `table.reloadData()` should also be reload in Main Queue, even if in theory the `UISearchBarDelegate` should be called in Main Thread, there is no need to resign the searchBar first responder with a dispatch async.

Comment: @Larme : I have try the dot notation, and still have no luck, see this : https://i.imgur.com/5ivinrj.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083630/lazyfilterbidirectionalcollectionresultsdatatype-to-expected-argument-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189689/why-cant-i-get-the-index-of-a-filtered-realm-list etc. There is an issue because the `filter` method you used returns an `Array`, but `places` is defined as being a LazyCollectionArray

Comment: @Larme : I wrapped it around an array and still get this : https://i.imgur.com/Rp4SzJr.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What also should work is if you are using `NSPredicate`

```
let bPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name contains[cd] %@", searchText)
places.filter(using: bPredicate)
```

Comment: Code clean, compile fine, but when I start typing, I don't see filter working. Anything I missed ?

Comment: @kyo Hi Kyo, sorry I was ill last week. Did it work for you now? Oh I see you modified the filter in your own answer a little bit :)

Answer (score 1):

## This is what I did

```
extension PlacesVC : UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        places = places?.filter("name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
        
        if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {

            load()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }

        }

        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and it is working perfectly

[image]

Hope this will help someone like me in the future.